# How to query more than 200 field; Salesforce SOQL Fields

Tags: salesforce

I am facing an issue using Salesforce API. While querying I am getting the following exception: "The SOQL FIELDS function must have a LIMIT of at most 200". Now, I understand SF expects a max of 200 only. So, I wanted to ask how can I query when the results are more than 200?

I can only use REST API to query, but if there is another option, then please let me know and I will try to add it in my code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it is Helpful:

```
// Get the Map of Schema of Account SObject
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();        

// Get all of the fields on the object
Set<String> setFieldNames = fieldMap.keySet();
list<String> lstFieldNames = new List<String>(setFieldNames);
         
// Dynamic Query String.
List<Account> lstAccounts = Database.query('SELECT ' + String.join(lstFieldNames, ',') + ' FROM Account');

system.debug('lstAccounts'+lstAccounts);
```

Comment: It's a decent illustration of the logical flow what needs to happen but bit useless for the OP. They mentioned REST API access, not Apex code. So demonstrate things like processing results of /services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Account/describe in lang of your choice?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. My first pref was REST, however as you have added Apex code, I will accept your answer as well. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could chunk it, SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account ORDER BY Id LIMIT 200. Read the id of last record and in next query add WHERE Id> '001...'. but that's not very effective.

Look into "describe" calls, waste 1 call to learn names of all fields you need and explicitly list them in the query instead of relying on FIELDS(ALL). You can compose SOQL up to 20k characters long and with "bulk API" queries you could fetch up to 10k records in each API call so "investing" 1 call for describes would quickly pay off.

You could even cache the describe's result in your application and fetch fresh only if something interesting changed, there's rest API header for that: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/sobject_describe_with_ifmodified_header.htm

Comment: Thank you so much, I do not need the describe call, as I exactly know the list of attributes I need. I was not aware that using Fields(ALL) will limit the query to 200 records only. Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: Haha, yeah, if you can spell them out upront that works even simpler. Write the query, call REST API, job done.

Comment: @eyescream the problem with this method is when there are too many fields for the API to handle...
I get the error
> Error Code 431. Response content: <h1>Bad Message 431</h1><pre>reason: Request Header Fields Too Large</pre>

Comment: Don't think I've encountered that. Saw some situations with queries over 100k characters... How would URI length impact the http headers? You're sure you're hitting normal Salesforce API and not some intermediary service?